# Intention of Encapsulation in embedded systems

Tags: c, variables, encapsulation

I am bit new to C programming and i would like to ask a certain question.
I'm using MPLAB c18 Compiler.

At first when I started coding  and ended up with lot of variables some were global and some were extern.

I found a certain statement in an article about encapsulation of variables.

```
Replacing
 float x;
 float y;
 float z;

 with these
 float X();
 float Y();
 float Z();
```

Is that an intention to do with

> local variables inside the respective functions  and assign
>
> local float x= float x(); local float y= float y();

I would appreciate your inputs and clarifications in this case.Am i Wrong regarding the interpretation.
So my question is ,whether the encapsulation is for reducing global and using more local variables in functions?

Regards

Comment: This is a very broad question, and depends very much on your design and the purpose of the program.

Comment: Well i'm just concerned whether the encapsulation used to reduce the global variables and Code reducing Crash/tracking back.

Comment: Global variables can be avoided by passing their values as arguments and return values between functions. Putting them in no-argument functions that track global state doesn't change the program structure much, it just introduces additional function calls.

Comment: @larsmans Thank you for your response.can you provide one eg : so that "Global variables can be avoided by passing their values as arguments and return values between functions".

Comment: @larsmans It would be extremley helpful if you can provide some eg of Passing values as arguments and return values between functions.

Comment: @Rookie91: simple: whenever a function needs `x`, pass it `x` as an argument. When multiple variables (almost) always need to be passed together, combine them in a `struct` and pass that. So `void printx() { printf("%f\n", (double)x); }` becomes `void printx(float x) {/*same*/}`.

Comment: @larsmans.Larsman I took it like this actually.If x=6;//or any random number, then  how can i pass x=6 as argument in foo(x1) where x1 is supposed to be 6.Sorry for troubling you again.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing "float x" (probably extern float x in some header) effectively encapsulates the variable.
You would probably need something like:

```
float x(); /* get x */
void setX(float newVal); /* set x here */
```

But that's rather general, the real implementation needs to be tailored to your needs (do you need a setter? do you need a getter? do you need to optimize this?).
In general, especially if you are rather new to C, encapsulation helps with a cleaner design and prevents simple mistakes.
For example, assuming that changing the value X involves performing some other task (say, X is the countdown for a nuclear missile launch sequence).
When encapsulating, your code would look something like:

```
void setX(float newVal){
    x = newVal;
    startNuclearLaunchSequence();
}
```

If you don't have this setter, you need to find all the places you set X (maybe by your colleagues as well) and manually launch your rockets, otherwise you'd get a misfire and then - bye bye apocalypse.
We don't want that, do we?

Comment: I needed both setter and getter btw :).So By this method we can limit variables to local and reduce global right?

Comment: True, you can assign the get() data to a local variable, manipulate it as needed and then assign it back using set().